# Is there a way to identify RNDIS connections/adaptors in Python? And then configure that adaptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rndis

I've multiple devices being connected and I need to identify and hopefully configure that RNDIS connection.

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent answer from using ifaddr
https://pythonhosted.org/ifaddr/